# Spring Dependency Injection by Constructor - Error creating bean, caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, constructor

I just started to learn Spring framework. I was learning about Spring Dependency Injection by Constructor and came across this error when I tried to run the code. Please help me resolve this error and explain what makes this error occure. Thank you.

Here is my code:

ActiveMQMessage.java

```
package com.infotech;

public class ActiveMQMessage {

    public void sendMessage() {
        System.out.println("Send message via ActiveMQMessage..");
    }
}
```

Communication.java

```
package com.infotech;

public class Communication {

    private ActiveMQMessage activeMQMessage;

    public Communication(ActiveMQMessage activeMQMessage) {
        super();
        this.activeMQMessage = activeMQMessage;
    }

    public void communicate() {
        activeMQMessage.sendMessage();
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="communication" class="com.infotech.Communication">
        <constructor-arg name="activeMQMessage" ref="activeMQMessage"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="activeMQMessage" class="com.infotech.ActiveMQMessage"></bean>

</beans>
```

Main.java

```
package com.infotech;

import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

        Communication communication = context.getBean("communication", Communication.class);

        communication.communicate();

        context.close();
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
Mei 30, 2018 9:13:55 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@3830f1c0: startup date [Wed May 30 09:13:55 ICT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Mei 30, 2018 9:13:55 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
Mei 30, 2018 9:13:55 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'communication' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$ParameterNameDiscoveringVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'communication' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$ParameterNameDiscoveringVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.infotech.Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$ParameterNameDiscoveringVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:116)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:89)
    at org.springframework.core.PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.java:67)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Note that XML configuration is generally considered old-style, and Java configuration (and better yet, Boot) is preferred. That said, it's not usual to inject a *message* object; generally, you'd inject a queue or other sort of long-lived connection, and then call methods with messages (short-lived) to send.

Comment: try to remove `super()` in `Communication ` class constructor.

Comment: @Mavlarn I've tried to remove super() but still get the same error. I end up changing the spring library from spring-framework-5.0.5 to spring-framework-4.2.6 and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I'd at least try removing the `name=` attribute from the `<constructor-arg>`. This is not strictly necessary if there is only one constructor that could possibly match, and while what you have seems like it *should* work, the error message does seem to indicate something related to name resolution.

Answer (score 0):

com.spring.core and com.spring.asm jar files must be different versions in your project.
asm jar hasnt been updated in a long time thats why you need to downgrade your core jar file.